# Help alphabetically sorting $terms from get terms('wpsc_product_category'

Tags: sort, plugin-wp-e-commerce, terms

I'm trying to get a list of wpsc_product_category terms, for a given category, and have them display in alphabetical order (by name) with links to their pages.

This gives me the right list, but the sort() doesn't work. The terms aren't in alphabetical order. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php 
//display sorted list of wpsc product categories
$category_id = 10;
$terms = get_terms('wpsc_product_category','hide_empty=0&parent='.$category_id);
sort($terms);
if ($terms) {
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        ?>
            <div>
                <div class="caption transparent_class">
                    <a href="<?php get_term_link( $term->slug, 'wpsc_product_category'); ?>" class="wpsc_category_link"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
                    <?php if(get_option('wpsc_category_description')) :?>
                    <?php echo '<div class="wpsc_subcategory">'.$term->description.'</div>'; ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works! Sorts by category name (visible name), produces a list of links of categories (that aren't empty) that are children of category_id.

```
<?php 
//display sorted list of wpsc product categories
$category_id = 10;
$terms = get_terms('wpsc_product_category','hide_empty=1&parent='.$category_id);
usort($terms, function($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->name, $b->name);
});
if ($terms) {
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        ?>
            <div>
                <div class="caption transparent_class">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->slug, 'wpsc_product_category'); ?>" class="wpsc_category_link"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
                    <?php if(get_option('wpsc_category_description')) :?>
                    <?php echo '<div class="wpsc_subcategory">'.$term->description.'</div>'; ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: As stayed in my answet `get_terms` has built in sorting  the default sort is by name. You should not need to sort the results after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

The [default sort order for `get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Parameters) is by `name`. That should give you an alphabetical order. Your `sort` is what is breaking that order. Your code should work if you just remove that `sort`.

Comment: Just realized, the initial code I posted DOES NOT work. It's missing an "echo" before the get_term_link.  And without the SORT, the list isn't right (as I believe it's sorting on the id field). I figured out both things and will past the corrected code below in case it helps someone else.

Comment: I didn't spot the missing `echo` but adding that `echo` is not relevant to the sorting problem.